# TableView com CheckBox - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estou preenchendo a `TableView` com uma `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`
e não estou utilizando uma tabela de modelo e sim obtendo os dados do `ArrayList`.

Ao marcar o `CheckBox`, preciso pegar os dados de uma coluna específica. Alguém tem um exemplo dessa maneira?

Já pesquisei bastante e todos os exemplos são referentes a uma classe que contém todos os dados.

Segue trecho do código da `TableView`:

```
ObservableList obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
colCod.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory("CAMPO0"));
colContrato.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory("CAMPO7"));
colCpf.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory("CAMPO1"));
colCliente.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory("CAMPO2"));
colProd.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory("CAMPO9"));
colValor.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory("CAMPO14"));
colStatus.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory("CAMPO15"));
colCk.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(colCk)); //definição do checkbox
```